# Print multiple .bat generated passwords to a .txt file

Tags: batch, passwords, printing

after searching this site for "how to generate a password with CMD" I found some very useful examples. Then, I wanted to be able to print more then one password at a time (who would want to click all day on that) and I found some code that it can run the generator code for a defined number of time. What I want to do next, is to try and print all of the generated passwords in a one single .txt file. I know you have to use the "command > [drive:\path*.txt]" for that but, I don't know how :/. After I combined the generator and the loop code I got something like this, but it prints only one password in the file. When the other one is generated, the old one is replaced. Any help? :D

```
@echo off
set execute counter=0
:loop
(@Echo off  
rem 16 stings pwd

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)

echo pwd=%pwd% > D:\password.txt
) :: This here between the () is the on line password generator
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="30" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

The > operator means: write to a textfile. If the textfile already exists, overwrite. If not, create a new file. This will undo your previous password.

The >> operator is what you need instead. It means: write to a textfile. If the textfile already exists, append to it. If not, create a new file.

So replace

```
echo pwd=%pwd% > D:\password.txt
```

with:

```
echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt
```

If you want to create a blank line in that same file, add:
    echo. >> D:\password.txt

Your output will then be:

```
pwd=randompass

pwd=randompass
```

This is useful if you want to store more info besides the password, for example:

```
set foruser /p "for which user is this?"

echo -------------- >> d:\password.txt
echo Password generated at %date% %time%. >> d:\password.txt
echo Password was made for user: %foruser%
echo pwd=randompass >> d:\password.txt
echo -------------- >> d:\password.txt
echo. >> d:\password.txt
```

Comment: Not working. It just opened the prompt and it closed (running only once the generator), and if I open it again, it dosen't generate a new one. I need it to print 10, 40, 90 (what ever number I difine) passwords in the same file :(.

Comment: Please check your code. I've coded a lot with .bat files and I know this by heart. it always worked for me, so if its not working, there must be something else going wrong.

Comment: I did just like you said...

@echo off
set execute counter=0
:loop
(@Echo off  
rem 16 stings pwd

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)

echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt

) :: This here between the () is the on line password generator
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="30" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
pause

Comment: Can you enter pause at the end of your batch file and run it, then check the output? any script error will show up at that point.

Comment: Also at the top, you write set execute counter=0. That space should be gone.

Comment: It looks like I forgot to delete this line from the code ":: This here between the () is the on line password generator" It works now, though a bit slow, 1 password every 3 seconds...

Comment: Good to hear. :)